# How we can arrange DateTime value in a required format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a Date value currently in `dd/MM/yyyy` format in a `string dateTimeValue` variable and a required format in `string dtFormat` variable, Format is based on Languages of diff countries.

```
string dateTimeValue  //contains date value currently in dd/MM/yyyy format
string dtFormat = GetDateFormat(langID);
```

Now based on the `dtFormat` I want to convert my `dateTimeValue`.
I tried this:

```
string FrmtddateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeValue).ToString(dtFormat);
```

but ended up with an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

How could we achieve this?

Comment: try this DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `ParseExact` on order to use the *format required* (`"dd/MM/yyyy"`) while parsing:

```
FrmtddateTimeValue = DateTime
  .ParseExact(dateTimeValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .ToString(dtFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if

> Format is based on Languages of ***diff countries***

you have to provide actual `CultureInfo` (instead of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the code).

**EDIT:** in order to find out the right culture you can use *Linq* over `CultureInfo.GetCultures`, e.g.

```
  String country = "Sri Lanka";

  var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(c => c.EnglishName.Contains(country)) // you may want more elaborated filter
    .FirstOrDefault();

  // si-LK
  Console.Write(culture.ToString());
```

Comment: @Dmity: Thanks for your response. I also wants to know that, How to get the actual CultureInfo? 
Also code throwing error for lang other than English: `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`

Comment: @Rahul Hendaw: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)` returns all the cultures, then filter out by, say, `EnglishName`

Comment: @Dmity: Any example/link for this will be really helpful.

Comment: @Rahul Hendaw: See my edit, just a *Linq* on `CultureInfo.GetCultures`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
FrmtddateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeValue.ToString(dtFormat));
```

Comment: Appreciate early response, but If you notice date is stored in dateTimeValue which is a string variable, It will show a overload exception. I wants to get the result in a string variable from a string value like - 
 `string FrmtddateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeValue.ToString(dtFormat));`
Please check..